# How to output last 5 minutes of a log file

Tags: logging, awk, sed, grep, solaris

I am running Solaris and my log file starts like this:

```
TID: [0] [AS] [2018-10-03 10:36:57,958] DEBUG...
```

I am looking to output only the last five minutes of the log file. I have tried SED/AWK/GREP but I think I have the wrong regex format.

EDIT: Code already used

```
d1=$(date --date="-10 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M") d2=$(date "+%b %_d %H:%M") while read line; do [[ $line > $d1 && $line < $d2 || $line =~ $d2 ]] && echo $line done

awk -vDate="date -d'TZ="UTC" now-10 minutes' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'" '$1" "$2 > Date {print Date, $0}'

sed -n "/^$(date --date='10 minutes ago' '+%b %_d %H:%M')/,\$p" <log file location here>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: d1=$(date --date="-10 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M")
d2=$(date "+%b %_d %H:%M")
while read line; do
    [[ $line > $d1 && $line < $d2 || $line =~ $d2 ]] && echo $line
done

Comment: sed -n "/^$(date --date='10 minutes ago' '+%b %_d %H:%M')/,\$p" <log file location here>

Comment: awk -vDate="`date -d'TZ="UTC" now-10 minutes' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'`" '$1" "$2 > Date {print Date, $0}'

Comment: please don't make readers wade thru hard to read comments to understand your problem. Your example code should be in the body of your Q (above). Use 4 spaces at the front of each line you want to appear formatted as code/data/error messages. Please read the [help] and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. AND, did you try searching for a solution here? It seems to me that this sort of Q gets asked almost every week. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, yes I did. The commands did not work for me.

Comment: Your Awk script might actually work if you used the right fields. In your example, the date is not in the fields `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: Good show, updating your Q. Now help save people's time by not having to read the same information in the comments (please delete them). Good luck.

Comment: This question is asked about once a week - search the archives.